# Zero Padding a Date with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to format a date like this:

`May 02 2013`

but at the moment, my formatting looks like this:

`May 2 2013`

How can I zero pad this type of date so that the *day* in the date is something like `02` instead of just `2`?

---

Here is the code I am using:

```
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
alert( m_names[curr_month] + " " +curr_date + " " + curr_year);
```

[jsFiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/fYvmV/)

Comment: If you are open to using a good JS lib, consider moment (http://momentjs.com/); otherwise you basically have to apply the left padded 0 yourself.

Comment: Using a lib simply for this trivial task is ridiculous.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can implement this logic like:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
console.log( m_names[curr_month] + " " +curr_date + " " + curr_year);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fYvmV/1/)

---

**UPDATES** - <sub><sup>( October 1st, 2017 )</sup></sub>

EcmaScript 2017 or ES8 has introduced two new String prototype methods:
[`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [`padEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd). We can add some extra spaces or dashes (or any other character), before or after a string. We can utilise it here like:

```
var curr_date = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2,0);
```

<sub><sup>( This syntax could have been shorter if we didn't need to convert **d.getDate()** to string, as **padStart** only works on string )</sup></sub>

**Demo:**

```js
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
  "October", "November", "December");

var d = new Date('10/1/2017');
var curr_date = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, 0);
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var formatted_date = m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_date + " " + curr_year;

console.log(formatted_date);
```

Comment: My favorite method that doesn't require libraries or extending prototypes.

Comment: other method would be to use `substring` and `length - 2`, but this is much more succinct, and extremely fast.

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/fYvmV/2/) is what you could to. Just see if the date is bigger than 9. If so use it, if not add a leading zero

```
var curr_date = d.getDate();
curr_date = curr_date > 9 ? curr_date : "0" + curr_date;
```

Comment: Not elegant but thoughtful

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Verify if `curr_date` is lower than 9. If yes, add `"0" + curr_date`.

So, you do this inline like bellow:

```
curr_date = (curr_date <= 9 ? "0" : "") + curr_date
```

Or, directly in alert:

```
alert( m_names[curr_month] + " " + 
       (curr_date <= 9 ? "0" : "") + curr_date + 
       " " + curr_year);
```

### Explanation

As you can see, I used [`?:` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

> In computer programming, `?:` is a ternary operator that is part of the syntax for a basic conditional expression in several programming languages. It is commonly referred to as the conditional operator, inline if (iif), or ternary if.

### How does it work?

It's simple! Look:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`
```

or

```
variable1 === variable2 ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

See updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fYvmV/3/).

Comment: What a write up for such a simple thing.

Comment: @crush, I like to give good answers. We are learning together.

Answer (score 1):

In the current dev version of Chrome (v28.0.1496.0), there is a `toPaddedString(n)` function on each Number object.

```
Number(16).toPaddedString(4)
"0016"
```

That's a pretty narrow browser to target, though, so I doubt it will do you much good.  It might be a part of the production version of Chrome too, but I don't have that version in front of me at the moment.  That function isn't part of EcmaScript 5.1, so it's best not to rely on it.  However, it isn't `[native code]`, so...

```
Number(1).toPaddedString
function g(k,j){var i=this.toString(j||10);return"0".times(k-i.length)+i}
```

So, to use this feature in any browser, include this line of code:

```
Number.prototype.toPaddedString = function g(k,j){var i=this.toString(j||10);return"0".times(k-i.length)+i};
```

Then your month can be padded, like so:

```
var curr_month = d.getMonth().toPaddedString(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cuentapendiente").focusout(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=""){
        $(this).val(zeroFill($(this).get(0).value,6))
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.

Answer (score -1):

This solution in coffeescript (wrapped into eco file) worked for me

```
<% zero_pad = (x) -> if x < 10 then '0'+x else ''+x %>
<% d = new Date() %>
<% m = d.getFullYear() %>
<% m += "-"+zero_pad (d.getMonth()+1) %>
<% m += "-"+zero_pad d.getDate() %>
<input type="date" name="date" width="20" value="<%- m %>">
```